# How to find duplicated data in the same table using script

Tags: sql

i need to fine duplicated users in my USERS table and insert to different table the user_id and the duplicated user_id.
I build this script and i don't know what's wrong in it.

```
BEGIN
FOR  v_user IN ( 
                  SELECT u.*
                  FROM users u
                  )
loop
       FOR v_dupUser IN (
                           SELECT u.*
                           FROM users u
                           WHERE u.email = v_user.email
                                 OR u.mobile_phone = v_user.mobile_phone
                                 OR u.land_line_phone = v_user.mobile_phone
                           )
       loop
           INSERT INTO DUPLICATES_USERS(id, user_id, dup_user_id,time_created) 
           VALUE (SEQ_DUPLICATED_USERS, v_user.id, v_DupUser,SYSDATE);
       end loop;
end loop;
END;
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be more including to go down a path like this;

```
insert into duplicated_users
 (select a.user_id user_id,
 b.user_id dup_user_id
 from users a
  , users b
 where (a.email = b_user.email
   OR a.mobile_phone = b_user.mobile_phone
   OR a.land_line_phone = b_user.mobile_phone)
  and a.user_id != b.user_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to use following query.

```
insert into duplicated_user 
(
    select * from [USER] where 
       user_id in (select user_id 
                     from [USER] 
                     group by user_id having count(user_id) > 1)
)
```